# Gulp bundle --ship: The build failed because a task wrote output to stderr

Tags: gulp, visual-studio-code

I've been getting this error when trying to do a `gulp bundle --ship` command:

> *The build failed because a task wrote output to stderr.
>   Exiting with exit code: 1*

I'm pretty new to this so have no idea how to proceed with it. It's happening even when I run through the helloworld webpart now. The `gulp serve` works and I can bundle and package the solution as long as I don't add a `--ship` to it. I've written and published apps before on the same machine so I don't know what is different now.

I've uninstalled every extension and re-installed the application but it's still doing it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have another update on this. I did a brand new install of visual studio code, node, gulp and the sharepoint framework on a brand new machine, as per this guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment and the issue flagged above shows up on that machine too. Is anyone else having this issue?

Comment: Further update. It now transpires that even if the bundle --ship fails you can run gulp package-solution --ship and it will now package the solution properly for upload.

Comment: More updates can be found [HERE](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/2131)

Comment: I am also getting same error, but I could able to deploy without any issue.

Answer (score 7):

Just for quick win you can use `--debug` flag for bundling task instead of `--ship` until this bug will be fixed in future releases:

```
gulp bundle --debug
gulp package-solution --ship
```

The bundled file will be bigger, but at least you are not getting "The build failed because a task wrote output to stderr" error in CI/CD.

Answer (score 6):

It normally happens because of the warnings. You can add suppression like mentioned below in gulpfile.js
build.addSuppression(`Warning - [sass] The local CSS class 'ms-Grid' is not camelCase and will not be type-safe.`);
build.addSuppression(`/Warning/gi`);

Comment: `build.addSuppression(/Warning/gi);` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because `caniuse-lite` needed a database update. It was confusing because there was no red error message.

Easy fix: `npx browserslist@latest --update-db`